# JMS Development Best Practice

Tags: java, jms, development-environment

In production we have multiple containers deployed and any one can be a consumer of one JMS queue. In our development environment, we have multiple developers each with a container that will potentially consume messages. When a developer wants to test something related to JMS by putting something on the queue, though, the message is often consumed by someone else which can be be a time sink.

We use the same build files for every environment. We do not want to accidentally deploy something to an upper environment that is meant strictly for the development environment.

What is a best practice in handling something like this that will not involve build tokens, etc or building differently for different environments?

We currently have the developer ask the other developers to comment out the consuming code, but this is a risk as the commented out code could accidentally get checked in.

One potential way would be to store a property in the database that would change from environment to environment.

How have you handled this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to share a single development JMS queue?

Comment: It is part of the existing architecture for production to spread processing across multiple containers. We like to keep our lower environments as close to production as possible. Having multiple queues in DEV could be a possible solution, but we still need to manage it so that we do not accidentally deploy something bad to PROD.

Comment: one of the great reasons you use tokens is so that you can have things like multiple queues in dev, and they won't accidentally make their way to prod, because dev configuration stays in dev and is not part of your prod deployment.

Comment: CM controls the build and has banned the use of build tokens.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've seen this done is for each developer to have their own topic, which is specific to their local dev environment. This depends on the developer having some control over the producer, obviously, not sure if this is viable for you.

You don't need build tokens to do this, but tokens do make things a lot nicer for local setup/configuration. I am quite surprised that you are able to use the same build files with no tokenization across every environment, I don't think I've ever worked on such a system.

Comment: Anything that changes across the environments is stored in the database.